# How to take snapshot of registry entries/folders before installing upgraded software?

Tags: testing, powershell, installation, registry, windows-installer

I am installing an major upgrade of product in my system.

Folders and registry entries will be updated for this.

I would like to take snapshot of folder structure and registry before/after installing update so that i can compare them easily.

Is there any tool or simple powershell module available to do this?

I hope testers would have done this while doing installation testing. If you have followed any good approach ,please update us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the best tools I've come across for before/after registry comparisons is called RegShot:

http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/regshot_portable

The 1.8.3 version supports 64 bit registries:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/

Yet another tool is called ZSoft Uninstaller:

http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/zsoft_uninstaller_portable

This one is tailored toward software installation analysis.

Both of these can perform registry and file system before/after comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Well, practically, I think you'll have to limit the paths you want to "monitor". You can use the PowerShell provider for registry very easily. For example:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE -recurse | Out-File HKCU_Software.reg
```

More information [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315270.aspx). Then, you can make a diff (before, after) using a tool like [DiffMerge](http://www.sourcegear.com/diffmerge/). Same principles for directories.

However, once again, beside a shallow check, I don't think that approach is realistic.

Don't know your context, but Microsoft's [Attack Surface Analyzer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24487) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for adding info Attack surface analyzer. I will try using that tool. Also your powershell cmdlet helped me. thanks for your commitment man.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) by NirSoft.

It could be particularly good for you as you mentioned PowerShell modules in your question, and RegistryChangesView has documented command-line options. RegistryChangesView also supports exporting the comparison to a .reg, HTML, or CSV file etc.

I'm still looking for a tool that can directly output the difference in the form of PowerShell commands; until then, I can export to a .reg file and then run it through a .reg-to-PowerShell-commands converter.

Other options include the classic [Regshot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) which has also been forked as [Regshot Advanced](https://github.com/skydive241/Regshot-Advanced). However, personally, I go with RegistryChangesView because I think it has better documentation/command-line options.